# Print matrix with white zeros gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

here's my problem: I need to print a matrix with gnuplot which has negative and positive entries but is very (VERY) sparse, so I want the white color to be associated with zeros. Is there any way in which this can be done (maybe starting from pm3d)? Thank you!

Comment: Is this what you want? `set palette defined (-1 'blue', 0 'white', 1 'red')`

Comment: No sorry, the problem was much more complicated. In the next few days I'll find the time to post the solution I figured out with a friend of mine.